# Deploying Polymer 2.0 project to Microsoft Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, publish, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I have followed basic docs and created a very basic Polymer web app and now I want to deploy it to my **Azure Web App**. I know VS 2017 provides easy way to just right click and deploy web apps with its built in templates, but in this case I created a project with `polymer cli`. So I don't really have an option to deploy it that way.

The following is the link of the docs on the page where they explain how to deploy on other platforms:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/toolbox/deploy

Comment: Is there an issue with git-deploy?

Comment: I dont know how to do a git deploy to azure web apps, I only know one way and that is through visual studio -> right click web project and publish them to web app on azure subscription

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on web apps and integration with version control such as git. Plenty of documentation on this.

Comment: can you please give me some link for that?

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic. But you're literally a web-search away (`azure web apps git`). The Azure site has all of this documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Git](https://git-scm.com/), you're able to deploy the Polymer project to Azure Web App with following steps.

### 1. Build your project

Go to the root of your Polymer app and run the following command:

```
polymer build --bundle
```

### 2. Commit your content

- Set up a repository by running the following command under `\build\default` folder:

  ```
  git init
  ```
- Use the following command to add files to your repository:

  ```
  git add -A
  ```
- Next, commit the changes to the repository by using the following command:

  ```
  git commit -m "Hello Azure App Service"
  ```

### 3. Follow the steps from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git#Step3) to enable the App Service app repository.

### 4. Deploy your project

- In your app's blade in the Azure Portal, click **Settings** > **Properties** for the **Git URL**.
- Use `git remote` to add the remote reference listed in Git URL. Your command will look similar to the following:

  ```
  git remote add azure https://<username>@<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/<appname>.git
  ```
- Push your content to App Service using the new **azure** remote you just created.

  ```
  git push azure master
  ```

Now, you can visit your app on the browser.

[image]